# Setting an IFRAME's style.height property doesn't have any effect on Android Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom

I have an HTML called 'parent.html' that displays 'child.html' in an IFRAME. I am trying to adjust the height of the IFRAME in the following manner.

```
f = document.getElementById('frame');
log('B: Frame height: ' + f.style.height);
log('B: Child offsetHeight: ' + f.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight);
log('B: Child scrollHeight: ' + f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
log('A: Frame height: ' + f.style.height);
```

It works on desktop browsers as can be seen in the screenshot of Google Chrome browser displayed on the left. It doesn't work on Android's default browser on Samsung Galaxy S II.

[image] [image]

## Browser details

Here are the user-agent strings of both the browsers, respectively:

1. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.41 Safari/536.5`
2. `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-gb; GT-I9100G Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1`

## HTML

Here is the complete code of 'parent.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
div#log {
    background: #333333;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}

iframe#frame {
    height: 200px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
var logDiv;
var f;

window.onload = function() {
    logDiv = document.getElementById('log');
    logDiv.innerHTML = 'Logger ready<br>';

    f = document.getElementById('frame');
    log('B: Frame height: ' + f.style.height);
    log('B: Child offsetHeight: ' + f.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight);
    log('B: Child scrollHeight: ' + f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
    f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
    log('A: Frame height: ' + f.style.height);
}

function log(msg)
{
    logDiv.innerHTML += msg + '<br>';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="frame" src="child.html">IFRAME not supported</iframe>
<div id="log">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the complete code of 'child.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Child</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer
fermentum, nunc eget bibendum imperdiet, est odio sagittis lectus,
volutpat viverra odio eros vel quam.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Questions

1. Is this an expected behaviour? Is there a document available online which describes what DOM objects I can manipulate in Android's browser and what I can't?
2. Is there any other way to resize the IFRAME in Android?

Comment: Can't you just drop the `iframe` and use a `div`?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa And then update the `div` by making an `XMLHttpRequest`? I can certainly do that. However, I would still like to know if there is a way to tackle this problem using `iframe`.

Comment: I have the same exact problem, with an embedded YouTube video... any news?